# Inference from a pre-trained model in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a pre-trained model from which I am trying to do inference in tensorflow. But I think I am missing something. Here is my architecture:

```
# Define a function to create a conv layer
def add_conv_layer(incoming=None, num_filters=None, kSize=None, pad='SAME', train=False, s=1,
                   layer_name=None, weights_param=None, bias_param=None, activation_fn=None):

    with tf.variable_scope(layer_name):

        previous_layer_output_shape = incoming.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
        tshape  = [kSize, kSize, previous_layer_output_shape, num_filters]

        # Set weights for the layer
        if weights_param is not None:
            weights = tf.Variable(weights_param, name='weights', dtype=tf.float32)
            weights = tf.reshape(weights, tshape)
        else:
            weights = init_weights(tshape)
            print weights.shape

        # Set bias for the layer
        if bias_param is not None:
            bias = tf.Variable(bias_param, name='bias', dtype=tf.float32)
        else:
            bias = init_bias(num_filters)


        layer = tf.nn.conv2d(incoming, weights, strides=[1,s,s,1], padding=pad, name='layer_name') + bias

        if activation_fn is not None:
            layer = activation_fn(layer)

        return layer    



# Define a function to add a dense layer
def add_dense_layer(input_tensor=None, num_units=None, layer_name=None,
                   weight_params=None, bias_params=None, activation_fn=None):

    with tf.variable_scope(layer_name):

        previous_layer_output_shape = input_tensor.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
        tshape = [previous_layer_output_shape, num_units]

        # Add weights for the layer
        if weight_params is not None:
            weights = tf.Variable(weight_params, name='weights', dtype=tf.float32)
            weights = tf.reshape(weights, tshape)    
        else:
            weights = init_weights(tshape)

        # Add bias to the layer    
        if bias_params is not None:
            bias = tf.Variable(bias_params, name='bias', dtype=tf.float32)
        else:
            bias = init_bias(num_units)


        layer = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights) + bias

        if activation_fn is not None:
            layer = activation_fn(layer)

        return layer


def build_network(features):
    features = tf.reshape(features, [-1,224,224,3])

    # Conv block 1
    conv1_1 = add_conv_layer(features, num_filters=64, kSize=3,  activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
                             weights_param=f['conv1_1']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv1_1']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv1_1')

    conv1_2 = add_conv_layer(conv1_1, num_filters=64, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
                             weights_param=f['conv1_2']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv1_2']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv1_2')

    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1_2,pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), name='pool1')



    # Conv block 2
    conv2_1 = add_conv_layer(pool1, num_filters=128, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                             weights_param=f['conv2_1']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv2_1']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv2_1')

    conv2_2 = add_conv_layer(conv2_1, num_filters=128, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
                             weights_param=f['conv2_2']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv2_2']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv2_2')

    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2_2,pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), name='pool2')



    # Conv block 3
    conv3_1 = add_conv_layer(pool2, num_filters=256, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
                             weights_param=f['conv3_1']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv3_1']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv3_1')

    conv3_2 = add_conv_layer(conv3_1, num_filters=256, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
                             weights_param=f['conv3_2']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv3_2']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv3_2')

    conv3_3 = add_conv_layer(conv3_2, num_filters=256, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                             weights_param=f['conv3_3']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv3_3']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv3_3')

    pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3_3,pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), name='pool3')


    # Conv block 4
    conv4_1 = add_conv_layer(pool3, num_filters=512, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                             weights_param=f['conv4_1']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv4_1']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv4_1')

    conv4_2 = add_conv_layer(conv4_1, num_filters=512, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                             weights_param=f['conv4_2']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv4_2']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv4_2')

    conv4_3 = add_conv_layer(conv4_2, num_filters=512, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                             weights_param=f['conv4_3']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv4_3']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv4_3')

    pool4 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv4_3,pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), name='pool4')



    # Conv block 5
    conv5_1 = add_conv_layer(pool4, num_filters=512, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
                             weights_param=f['conv5_1']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv5_1']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv5_1')

    conv5_2 = add_conv_layer(conv5_1, num_filters=512, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
                             weights_param=f['conv5_2']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv5_2']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv5_2')

    conv5_3 = add_conv_layer(conv5_2, num_filters=512, kSize=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                             weights_param=f['conv5_3']['weights'].value,
                             bias_param=f['conv5_3']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='conv5_3')

    pool5 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv5_3,  pool_size=(7,7),strides=(7,7), name='img1_pool5')

    flatten_layer = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(inputs=pool5)

    fc6 = add_dense_layer(flatten_layer, num_units=1024, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
                               weight_params=f['fc6']['weights'].value, 
                               bias_params= f['fc6']['bias'].value,
                               layer_name='fc6')


    fc7 = add_dense_layer(fc6, num_units=256, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                          weight_params=f['fc7']['weights'].value, 
                          bias_params= f['fc7']['bias'].value,
                          layer_name='fc7')
    output = add_dense_layer(fc7, num_units=2, activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,
                             weight_params=f['out']['weights'].value, 
                             bias_params= f['out']['bias'].value,
                             layer_name='output')

    return output
```

Now, I want to run feed the `build_network` function a new input and take the inference. I was doing this as shown(which I think is wrong):

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
out = build_network(features)
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
     print(out.eval())
```

But with this, I am getting same output for every input. Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Edited from the original**: <strike>Your `build_network` function creates the graph only. The `sess.run(init)` line initializes the network's weight with the default initializers for each weight, i.e. your network after that line is **not** trained.</strike>

After adding to the code your implementation of te `add_*_layer` functions, I see now that you do in fact initialize the weights.
The further information in the comments to this answer suggests that the error might lie in the conversion of weights from Theano to Tensorflow or, as suggested by @Sebastian, in a difference in the data layout.
Without further information, though, it's hard for me to say more with certainty.

Comment: I have loaded the weights for conv layers and dense layers from my disk. That's why I defined the `add_conv_layer` and `add_dense_layer` function separately for loading the custom weights

Comment: could you add the code of these functions to your question too?
I suspect the weights get overwritten when you use the `global_variables_initializer`

Comment: added those functions

Comment: Uhm looks like you're initializing the values correctly. Are the weights coming from a different framework? (e.g. Keras?)

Comment: Yup...coming from theano. Also, I have changed them  accordingly so that they are compatible with tensorflow

Comment: I see... are you 100% sure of the compatibility? I can't think of a reason why this would not work besides the weights being somehow broken.

Comment: I followed this guide: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/wiki/Converting-convolution-kernels-from-Theano-to-TensorFlow-and-vice-versa

Comment: The guide talks specifically of convolution weights. What about your fully connected layer?

Comment: I don't think that matters because only convolution implementation is different in theano and tensorflow

Comment: I don't think the weights are going to be overwritten if you run the global_variabels_initializer, just initialized (i.e., memory will get allocated). For now, during the debugging stage, I suggest you try to use `constant` instead of `Variable` and don't train your network but just use it for inference to get that part working first.

Comment: Regarding an other issue, the potential incompatibility between Theano and TensorFlow, it may be that it expects a different layout. E.g., TensorFlow uses "NHWC", where the data is stored in the order of: [batch, height, width, channels]. I haven't used Theano in 2 years or so and forgot, but the format could be "NCHW": [batch, channels, height, width].

Comment: You are right, the answer was written before he added the code for the `add_*_layer` functions, I'll update it with the info in these comments

Comment: @Sebastian I converted the weights accordingly.

Comment: @Sebastian Even after converting `Variable` to `constant`, the problem remains the same